# Dynamic page loading frpm php and search engines

Tags: web-development, search-engines

My web site includes many topics and has multiple depth level menus with multiple pages attached to each menu.
To keep track of everything every link is sent to an index.php
It has 2 get arguments from which the code determines the correct file to load.

The index.php includes the correct file using those 2 get arguments.

The links of the menu look something like this:

```
    <a filename='diktia/history/history.php' href='index.php?menuId=diktia&itemId=diktiaItem0'>Ιστορία</a>
```

etc...

I wonder how this will affect the search engines and consequently the appearance of my site on the search results since they will not be able to go the the actual pages when they follow the links.
Should i try a different approach using actual links?

Comment: What is the `filename` attribute used for?  I don't think that is a valid HTML5 attribute for an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Static, semantic links are typically better for SEO for two reasons. One, search engines can figure out the hierarchy better when it is built into the link structure. Two, it's a better user experience because users also get a clue about your hierarchy just by looking at the URL.

However, search engines do recognize query strings. As long as you don't have those pages set to noindex, Googlebot and others should be able to follow the links and index the individual pages.

Long term, setting up static, semantic links would give you a number of benefits, but you should still be able to rank and get visitors (if the content and other code are reasonably SEO-friendly) with your current setup. But, you should choose now - while the site is new. Changing URL structures once a site is well-indexed is hard to execute well - you need to redirect every page 1:1 - and can cause ranking losses and links to break, so now is the time to decide and then stick with your structure.